# Oracle APEX Refresh Interactive Grid after Close Dialog

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I'm working with Apex Version 20.1 and my problem is the following:

I have an interactive grid with a link column which referes to a modal dialog.

After closing this dialog with a "Close Dialog" process, the grid should be refreshed. I've changed to Event Scope dynamic and static container is the static id from my interactive grid. This works fine, but just once ! When the grid is refreshed and i open and close the dialog again, nothing happens !! What's missing here?

Thank you

Anja

Comment: This works fine for me on 21.1 Could you put a simple example together on a workspace on apex.oracle.com ? Use emp/dept sample dataset and pass credentials. Happy to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E39147_04/advnc_dynamic_actions.htm#CIHGAFFI) there are two types of event scope: Static and Dynamic, the dynamic scope is described as following:

> Dynamic - Binds the event handler to the triggering elements for the
> lifetime of the current page, including any elements that are updated
> by Partial Page Refresh (PPR). Specifying Dynamic causes an additional
> field Static Container (jQuery Selector) to be displayed. Specifying a
> Static Container can help improve the performance of the way events
> are handled with a Dynamic Event Scope. This should be an element on
> the page that itself does not get re-created, but contains the
> triggering elements that are re-created using Partial Page Refresh
> (PPR). This element reference must be defined as a jQuery selector.
> For example if you have a dynamic action that does something to the
> rows of an interactive report region (which is re-created by PPR),
> this would need an Event Scope of Dynamic, in order for the dynamic
> action to still work after the report has been refreshed. And here,
> the Static Container value could be set to a jQuery selector selecting
> the region's Static ID value, for example: '#my_region'.

the static ID must be an element on the page that itself does not get recreated, but contains the triggering elements that are recreated using Partial Page Refresh (PPR). Which means you cant use the static ID of the IG, but you can still use a JQuery selector of an Elements which is parent of the IG (for example *body* selector)